# SQL Query doesn't run correctly

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have the next tables in my database. I need to determine all the books purchased by an user, and all users who bought a specific book.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMJdw.png

these are my sql requests, but something goes wrong:

```
select * 
from Livres 
where idCatalogue_fk in (
    select idCatalogue_fk 
    from ProduitsEtCommandes 
    where idCommande_fk in (
        select idCommande_fk 
        from CommandesEtUtilisateurs 
        where idUtilisateur_fk=1
    )
);


select * 
from Utilisateurs 
where idUtilisateur in (
    select idUtilisateur_fk 
    from CommandesEtUtilisateurs 
    where idCommande_fk in (
        select idCommande_fk 
        from Catalogue 
        where idCatalogue in (
            Select idLivre 
            from Livres 
            where idCatalogue=1 
            and title='Poezii'
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: These are nested `SELECT` statements.  You are better off with `JOIN`s

Comment: What goes wrong? Can you provide sample data and desired output?  Edit your question to include some of these details.

Comment: what do you mean "something goes wrong"?

Comment: in the data model.... the `idUtilisasteur_fk` in `produitsEtCommandes` is spelled differently than the table name `utilisateurs`... there's an extra `s`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know French... *there might be spelling errors* with the table and column names... use the `where` to add your filters for specific users or books.

**edit**

could you just do this?  (if this is homework, this isn't a very good example of a database model... btw)

```
select * from livres where idCatalogue_fk in ( 
     select idCatalogue_fk from produitsEtCommandes where idUtilisasteur_fk=1 
  );


-- note the misspelling comment i made up top... the ID in productsNCommands
select * from utilisateurs where idUtilisateurs in ( 
         select idUtilisasteur_fk from produitsEtCommandes where idCatalogue_fk in (
                                 select idCatalogue_fk from livres where idLivre=1
                              ) 
      );
```

---

basically... according to the data model, you need to:

- join livres
- join catalogue
- join produitsEtCommandes
- join commandes

and that will give you every livre-commande association.  then just filter based on your needs.

to find all books associated with the user Kim (assuming only one user with that name):

```
select   * 
from     livres 
         join catalogue on livres.idCatalogue_fk=catalogue.idCatalogue 
         join produitsEtCommandes on produitsEtCommandes.idCatalogue_fk=catalogue.idCatalogue 
         join commandes on commandes.idCommande=produitsEtCommandes.idCommande_fk 
where    commandes.nomClient = 'Kim'
```

so.... can you do this, then.....?

```
select * from livres where idLivre in ( 
             select   distinct idLivre
             from     livres 
                      join catalogue on livres.idCatalogue_fk=catalogue.idCatalogue 
                      join produitsEtCommandes on produitsEtCommandes.idCatalogue_fk=catalogue.idCatalogue  
             where    idCommandes_fk=1)
```

or....  (so ugly)

```
select   * 
from     livres, catalogue, produitsEtCommandes, commandes 
where    livres.idCatalogue_fk=catalogue.idCatalogue and 
         produitsEtCommandes.idCatalogue_fk=catalogue.idCatalogue and 
         commandes.idCommande=produitsEtCommandes.idCommande_fk and 
         livres.title = 'Brave New World'
```

oh, noes....

```
select * from livres where idCatalogue_fk in (
      select distinct idCatalogue from catalogue where idCatalogue in (
                       (select distinct idCatalogue_fk from produitsEtCommandes where idCommandes_fk=1)
               )
      )
```

Comment: the problem is that I am not allowed to use inner join, just select in select

Comment: that's dumb... i can't see a reason you would ever have a condition like that imposed on you in real life... i mean... maybe in MS Access or something... lol.  i don't know.

Comment: @nike - i don't understand the rules.  no joins anywhere?  so can i do the old school/traditional join in the where part?

Comment: @gloomy.penguin thanks, i modified the tables it worked, even better than I expected